# Factory Girl Nested Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, tdd, factory-bot

I have several Rails models with nested relationship using has_one through, and no matter how I seem to structure my FactoryGirl factories I can't get the relationship to be correctly setup.

Models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :subscription
    has_one :plan, through: :subscription
    has_one :usage_limit, through: :plan
end

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :plan
    belongs_to :user
end

class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :subscriptions
    belongs_to :usage_limit
    has_many :users, through: :subscriptions
end

class UsageLimit < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :plan
end
```

No matter how I structure my factories, I seem to end up with a users plan not being equal to its subscription plan, or I can't setup the usage_limit due to "it goes through more than one other association". I've tried using callbacks to no luck, anybody got any idea how I can factory these models and relationships?

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :plan do
        name                    "Test Plan 1"
        price                   19.99
        active                  true
        usage_limit
    end


FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :subscription do
        active_subscription     true
        on_trial_period         false
        coupon_used             false
        free_account            false
        plan
        user

        after(:create) do |s|
            s.user.subscription = s
            # s.user.plan = s.plan
        end
    end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :usage_limit do
        keywords_per_month      2
        discoveries_per_month   2
        keywords_per_discovery  5
    end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :user do
        email                  "user@example.com"
        password               "password"
        password_confirmation  "password"
        plan

        after(:create) do |user|
          # user.subscription = FactoryGirl.build(:subscription, :user => user, :plan => user.plan)
          # user.usage_limit = user.plan.usage_limit
        end
    end
end
```

**I'd like to be able to just `let!(:user) { FactoryGirl.build(:user) }` and have all of the correct relationships created.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `create` instead of `build`. This should work:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    after(:create) do |user|
      user.subscription = FactoryGirl.create(:subscription)
    end
  end

  factory :plan do
    usage_limit
  end

  factory :subscription do
    plan
  end

  factory :usage_limit do
  end
end

require 'rails_helper'

describe User do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  it "has a subscription" do
    expect(user.subscription).to_not be_nil
  end

  it "has a plan" do
    expect(user.plan).to_not be_nil
    expect(user.plan).to eq user.subscription.plan
  end

  it "has a usage limit" do
    expect(user.usage_limit).to_not be_nil
    expect(user.usage_limit).to eq user.plan.usage_limit
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

`FactoryGirl.build` does not persist to the database. You may need `FactoryGirl.create`.